Is there any way to grep a binary plist?
When working in a terminal, I want to use grep on a binary plist file. Is there any command or utility that will print the contents of a binary plist to stdout so that I can grep through it?

You can use plutil -p foo.plist | grep ... or plutil -convert xml1 -o - bar.plist | grep ... to search your string in a text representation.

@nohillside's answer is certainly the canonical one. But, if you're willing to spare an additional 20ms or so of cpu time, this Python solution may also be useful:
https://github.com/luckman212/plistgrep
It handles multiple files, and produces results in JSON.
Example output
$ plistgrep 'Shown?' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist
{
  "filename": "/Users/luke/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist",
  "match_count": 4,
  "matches": [
    {
      "matched_string": "Show",
      "key": "ABShowPeoplePickerDebugPanel",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "matched_string": "Shown",
      "key": "NSToolbar Configuration NSPreferences/TB Is Shown",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "matched_string": "Shown",
      "key": "ABLastImportShown",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "matched_string": "Show",
      "key": "ABShowDebugMenu",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}

If no matches are found, the program's exit code will be 1. So by redirecting its output to the bitbucket, it could be used in a shell script similarly to grep -q:
if ! plistgrep Foo /path/to/bar.plist &>/dev/null ; then
  echo "nothing found, proceeding to Baz the Quuxes..."
  ...
fi


Not sure whether I'll ever get used to command-line utilities outputting JSON. Probably I'm just getting old :-)

@nohillside I considered adding a flag to select JSON or plaintext output, but jq is pretty ubiquitous these days, and rather than adding a bunch of argparse code, I chose to "keep it simple". If you want, you can emulate the output of plutil -p with something like plistgrep 'Shown?' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist | jq -r '.matches[] | "\(.key) => \(.value)"'

Thanks for the jq options, I'm usually happy when I remember ... | jq . :-)
